# How to avoid webview links opening in the same webview

Tags: android, android-webview

When a user clicks on a link in the `webview`. I want to show a dialog asking whether the user wants to view it in default browser, if he opts YES then he should be taken to default browser otherwise it shouldn't load the link at all.
But, the issue I am facing is, I could able to show the dialog inside `run()` of `WebViewClient's` overridden method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`. When the user opts YES I am doing `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url)));` to show it in default browser. But, irrespective of the user selects for YES/NO it is showing the link in `webview` which I want to avoid. Any suggestions appreciated...TIA

Comment: inside run() of WebViewClient? show your YES/NO logic also.

Comment: Oh!!! I resolved the issue, by just reloading the same URL inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, by just reloading the same URL inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html